# Failed to start mysql server : A start job for unit mysql.service has failed

Tags: server, mysql

Im unable to start mysql server after update from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04
Below is the result after running `journalctl -xe` to check log

```
-- The job identifier is 6019 and the job result is done.
Aug 15 19:35:13 System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 15 19:35:13 System-Product-Name systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 15 19:35:13 System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6019 and the job result is failed.
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, please share what you have tried thus far to fix the issue and the result of those commands.

Comment: Tried this fix, but still no good https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603349/errormysqld-service-start-request-repeated-too-quickly-on-manjaro

Comment: Speaking from experience, you will want to grab your most recent database backups, remove MySQL completely, and rebuild. 18.04 shipped with MySQL 5.x. 20.04 shipped with 8.0. The number of changes between the two versions are no joke. A lot of upgrades straight-up fail, particularly those that use MyISAM tables or data types that were deprecated in MySQL 5.3 and earlier.

Comment: Check `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. It's very likely to have useful information.